# Boostrap v5 carousel not sliding

Tags: carousel, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-carousel

The carousel fades into the next slide when I click the next/previous buttons, even though I have added the 'slide' class.

```
<div id="testimonials-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active"  style="background-color: red;">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: yellow;">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-color: blue;">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonials-carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonials-carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

I want the slides to slide smoothly and not fade. Can you guys tell me if I'm doing something wrong or guide me through how I should be doing it

Answer (score 0):

your code work and no problem and slide smoothly, try this strucktur in your html

```
<head>
<link href="your.css" />
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

</head>
<body>

//your html

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```